# Резиновые элементы посредством @media или других средств

Tags: css, вёрстка

Опыта в оптимизации элементов под ширину экрана у меня нет. Хочу сделать резиновый прямоугольник и слова слева\права, которые тянулись бы при изменении определенных разрешений ширины экрана: 1920 - 1366 - 360 (или хотя-бы 1280 - 1366 - 1920, ибо при 360 я так полагаю нужно писать сайт для мобильной версии, а так пусть открывает полную версию (?) ). Вернусь к сути проблемы:
Я попробовал сделать своеобразную резинку посредством @media в css, но слово слева\справа даже при изменении width в 100px (здесь я оставил как было до, с 100px я просто проверял) - соответственно уезжает под прямоугольник.

```css
a{
text-decoration: none;
font-family: arial;
color: black;
}
.image {
display: block;
text-align: center;
line-height: 200px;
position:absolute;
font-size:40px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1366px) and (max-width:1920px) {
.next { display:block; height: 23px; width: 40px; position: relative; 
 left:1170px; top:425px; }
.prev {   display:block; height: 23px; width: 40px; position: relative; 
left:570px; top:400px; }
.slider { position: relative; margin-left:650px; margin-top:300px;}
.image {  display: block; line-height: 133px; font-size: 40px;  }
```

```html
<div class="next"><a href="#">next</a></div>
<div class="prev"><a href="#">previous</a></div>

<div class = "slider">
    <div class="image first">FIRST</div>
    <div class="image">SECOND</div>
    <div class="image">THIRD</div>
    <div class="image">FOURTH</div>
    <div class="image last">FIFTH</div>
</div>
```

Если с помощью @media - то как адаптировать эти 3 контейнера, чтобы при изменении экрана они тянулись с малой погрешностью в своих размерах и отступах относительно друг друга?
и
Есть ли какие-то другие способы сделать данные объекты тянущимися, желательно прямо пропорционально изменению экрана? (jQuery, к примеру; решение в коде JS, пожалуйста, не предлагать, я его не пойму).
Текст я помнится подстраивал под изменения с помощью font-size: 1.3vw ,  но как подстроить контейнер...
Буду признателен Вам за помощь\советы в решении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут механизм не сложный и потому надо просто понять : что конкретно мы должны сделать что бы  элементы карусели стали влазить в любое разрешение экрана..

В моём случае я с вашего примера взял всего два элемента и вынес их в переменную и этой css переменной я манипулировал в медиа запросе ну в общем смотрите

```css
:root {
  --size: 760px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  width: var(--size);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider-wrap {
  width: calc(var(--size) * 5);
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.image {
  width: var(--size);
  background: #cc0000;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}


/*pagination*/

.next {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media (max-width:960px) {
   :root {
    --size: 640px;
    --wrapper: 768px;
  }
  .slider {
    width: var(--size);
  }
  .slider-wrap {
    width: calc(var(--size) * 5);
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: var(--wrapper);
  }
  .image {
    width: var(--size);
  }
}

@media (max-width:771px) {
   :root {
    --size: 480px;
    --wrapper: 640px;
  }
  .slider {
    width: var(--size);
  }
  .slider-wrap {
    width: calc(var(--size) * 5);
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: var(--wrapper);
  }
  .image {
    width: var(--size);
  }
}

@media (max-width:641px) {
   :root {
    --size: 360px;
    --wrapper: 480px;
  }
  .slider {
    width: var(--size);
  }
  .slider-wrap {
    width: calc(var(--size) * 5);
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: var(--wrapper);
  }
  .image {
    width: var(--size);
  }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
   :root {
    --size: 280px;
    --wrapper: 400px;
  }
  .slider {
    width: var(--size);
  }
  .slider-wrap {
    width: calc(var(--size) * 5);
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: var(--wrapper);
  }
  .image {
    width: var(--size);
  }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
   :root {
    --size: 400px;
    --wrapper: 400px;
  }
  .slider {
    width: var(--size);
  }
  .slider-wrap {
    width: calc(var(--size) * 5);
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: var(--wrapper);
  }
  .image {
    width: var(--size);
  }
  .next {
    opacity: 0.3;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    width: 100px;
  }
  .prev {
    opacity: 0.3;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="next"><a href="#">next</a></div>

  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div class="image">FIRST</div>
      <div class="image">SECOND</div>
      <div class="image">THIRD</div>
      <div class="image">FOURTH</div>
      <div class="image">FIFTH</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="prev"><a href="#">previous</a></div>
</div>
```

[вот тут тоже самое](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/pqMzRj)